# Gmail - Web Driver Automate

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Here is the code I am trying to automate Gmail through Web Driver.

I found something weird. Whenever I am commenting out the line to find the `Password (Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys("SRS");)`

then Web Driver is successfully clicking on "`Sign In`" button

but when I un-comment the line

```
(Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys("SRS");)
```

then Web Driver is not able to click on Sign In button also and it gives the error message that [Unable to find the Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wDiP.png) Xpath however still its on Email id Screen only

[Here is the attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8cKb.png) screenshot

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Gmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Driver.get("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/");
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/nav/div/a[2]")).click();
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Enter the Gmail ID
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']")).sendKeys("RK12@gmail.com");
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Click on Next Button
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']")).click();
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys("SRS");
        //Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You are giving wrong email id, hence Google validated it and shown that the error message as "Sorry, Google doesn't recognize that email".

So, enter valid email id in order to proceed to password page.

**2.** Here, with the code in the question, gives `ElementNotVisibleException`, hence added `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` to make sure that password field is loaded before sending the keys.

**Updated code:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Gmail {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Driver.get("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/");
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/nav/div/a[2]")).click();
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Enter the Gmail ID
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']")).sendKeys("rbnaveen558@gmail.com");
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Click on Next Button
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']")).click();
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 10);
        WebElement pwd = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Passwd")));
        pwd.sendKeys("SRS");
        //Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add "sign in" button also,i tested this.This is working fine.
   `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys("SRS");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //click to sign in
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();`